# AJAX error handling with jQuery: should I use $.ajaxSetup() or $.fn.ajaxError()

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling

I want to alert the user whenever there's an AJAX error. You can do this via `$.ajaxSetup`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
  error: function() {
    alert("OOPS!")
  }
});
```

[But the jQuery docs recommend against this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

> Note: Global callback functions should
>   be set with their respective global
>   Ajax event handler
>   methods-.ajaxStart(), .ajaxStop(),
>   .ajaxComplete(), .ajaxError(),
>   .ajaxSuccess(), .ajaxSend()-rather
>   than within the settings object for
>   $.ajaxSetup().

So I guess I'm supposed to do this:

```
$("#some_random_div").ajaxError(function() {
  alert("OOPS!")
});
```

This doesn't make sense to me: the AJAX error callback pertains to my application as a whole, not a specific page element. So why should the callback function be associated with an individual page element?

So: why do the jQuery docs recommend using what looks like a less readable approach, and which approach is best?

Comment: I prefer ajaxSetup for this purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical use is that the specific page element you bind ajaxError to is the div where your error message is going to be displayed; perhaps a "flash" message div at the top of your page.  This way you have direct access to that div to append your message.

But if you're not using a particular DOM element as your message display area, you could certainly bind it to `$(document)` or some other such global element.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.9, the ajax events should only be used on `document` anyway, so it should read like `$(document).ajaxError(function(){ ... })` or `$(document).on("ajaxError", function(){ ... })`. The reason the docs say not to use `$.ajaxSetup()` for this is they are only the *default* settings for a request; any request that defines its own `error` handler would clobber the one set in `$.ajaxSetup()` which is probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The docs state:

As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxError() method should only be attached to *document*.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Answer (score 0):

You can wire up the error function to the whole body like this:

```
$('body').ajaxError(function() {
    alert("OOPS!")
});
```

Comment: But isn't that less readable than the `ajaxSetup()` approach? I.e., the function here has *nothing* to do with the document's body (put another way, if I could achieve the same exact effect by substituting "body" for *any* other element, this seems like the wrong approach)

Answer (score 0):

There may exist circumstances where it might relate to an individual control - such as when you have an autocomplete that round trips to the database via ajax, as opposed to an entire page like on a submit.  This would then determine if you want to isolate the error on a component of the page and if so what the response to the error should be rather than with a more generic approach.

---